# Add to list in python if list is value in dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a dictionary to a list that is itself the value in a dictionary key value pair.

```
user_data = {
    "watched": []
    }
movie = {
    "title": 'Title A',
    "genre": 'Horror',
    "rating": 3.5
}
```

How would I add the movie value to the watched list value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```py
In [2]: user_data["watched"].append(movie)

In [3]: user_data
Out[3]: {'watched': [{'title': 'Title A', 'genre': 'Horror', 'rating': 3.5}]}
```

Note that accessing a dictionary returns the value associated with the given key, so `user_data["watched"]` gives us the `list` object associated with that key `"watched"`. Since we have a `list`, we can use the `.append()` method to add the `movie` dictionary to the list.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought! Then the test is failing for a different reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is:

```
user_data["watched"].append(movie)
```

In addition, If you have a list of movies like:

```
movie = [
  {
    "title": 'Title A',
    "genre": 'Horror',
    "rating": 3.5
  },
  {
    "title": 'Title B',
    "genre": 'Action',
    "rating": 4
  }
]
```

then you can use the assignment operator

```
user_data["watched"] = movie
```

Comment: `.extend()` would be a better choice for the second case.